# error building maven project due to frontent-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build/complie a maven project that uses the front-end-maven plugin. However when compelling the project I get this error within IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project PROJECT-NAME: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26 requires Maven version 3.1.0
```

I had Maven 3.3.3 installed so have downgraded it too 3.1.1 however I still receive the same error.

This is the section in my POM.xml file which details the plugin:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.26</version>

                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/web</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v0.12.7</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>2.11.3</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>gulp dev build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>gulp</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>dev-once</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

When running `mvn clean install --debug` in the terminal I get the error;

```
   [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Found proxies: []
[INFO] Installing node version v0.12.7
[INFO] Creating temporary directory /Users/folder/Development/BSD/eng-bsd-bigted-server-ice-tea/src/web/node_tmp
[INFO] Downloading Node.js from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-darwin-x64.tar.gz to /Users/folder/Development/BSD/eng-bsd-bigted-server-ice-tea/src/web/node_tmp/node.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
Nov 03, 2015 1:41:30 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request: No route to host
Nov 03, 2015 1:41:30 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
```

Comment: The error is clear: "The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26 requires Maven version 3.1.0". Are you using Maven 3.1.0?

Comment: hmmm I kind of assumed it work with version 3.1.1

Comment: Does the same happen if you run Maven on the command-line? Could you add --debug to the Maven options and post the output?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKoch Please see my edited question

Comment: Looks like you habe a network Problem. Perhaps you need to configure a proxy? You can do this in the .m2/settings.XML in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

User version 0.0.22 of the frontend-maven-plugin. That one does not require Maven 3.1.1. It works with lower version of Maven as well.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions (I use 20.04) of IntelliJ, enable the use plugin registry option within the Maven settings:

1. Click **File** -> **Settings**.
2. Expand **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Maven**
3. Check **Use plugin registry**.
4. Click **Apply** and OK.

I expect it would be something similar in Eclipse and other IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing the issue on version 1.9.1, can try and upgrade the version 1.12.1. Which fixed the issue for me.